# Application closes without any Error when orientation changes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

i have created two layouts for portrait and landscape differently
layout.xml is in both `layout` for portrait mode and in `layout-land` it works fine on some devices but when i run that application in some low configuration devices after two or three time of changing the orientation the application closes without giving any kind of error.

i have also included `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` in AndroidManifest.xml

P.S. there is one activity which has two xml for portrait and landscape and the activity contains a fragment which has two xml for portrait and landscape.

**Edit**
onCreate of my code is here:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    View v = findViewById(R.id.home_view);
    v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);


    initViews();

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        //maintaining state
    }

}
```

Comment: Without actual code and/or the layouts in question it will be hard to help you :p, can you post some here ?

Comment: add activity  also <activity android:name=".Activity1"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">

Comment: post your activity class code

Comment: i have added the onCreate of my code

Comment: Have you overridden the `onConfigurationChanged()` method ??

Comment: use `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout"`

Comment: @SharpEdge overriding that method was never needed

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar actually that is your problem, Im using the same scenario layout-land.. and I've done my initialization in `onConfigurationChanged()` method.. if you decide to put `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` then you have to override that method.

Comment: ok @SharpEdge i will try your solution and see if its working or not

Comment: is there any code we have to write inside `onConfigurationChanged()` method

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar check my answer

Comment: check once the both XML & there id's for view & Layout if your using Relative Layout.

Comment: there is no issue of id's the orientation is changed one or two times normally but on then at third time it crashes

Comment: the app closes when i run it in 1gb ram device or below but runs perfectly on 2 gb ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all like everyone else pointed out, only using `"orientation|keyboardHidden"` is not enough

You have to use `screenSize` as well..

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

And in your activity.. You have to override the `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` method ..

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initViews();  // initialize your views again..

}
```

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar this works because I have used this in my app. You have to initialize your views again in `onConfigurationChanged()` method.. check my updated answer

Comment: when using your code it does not change the layout xml file it take the xml layout file which was first used if opened in portrait mode it will use the portrait xml for landscape also

Comment: i dont want that to happen

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar you must use the same name for the xml files in both folders.. have you got different names ??

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar my solution worked for you rite ? glad I could help and thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: it was not a complete solution but it helped me, the thing that mostly helped me was i was using attach detach for fragments instead of that i used replace and it worked like a charm